# Change the time of a date

Tags: date, grails

If I use

> new Date()

it returns me date with time stamp of the current time.
How can I change the date appended with the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You coudl use the [set method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#set%28java.util.Map%29) to modify your date instance:

```
def date = new Date()
date.set(second: 0, minute: 0, hourOfDay: 15)
```

If you don't need any time you could also use [clearTime()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime%28%29) to remove the time portion of your date.